# How can I customize save and publish in Umbraco back office (admin panel)?

Tags: asp.net, events, umbraco

For example, before save and publish a data,I want manipulate data (process on data) such as checking data, add an URL shorter to the UrlRewriting.config file and like these automatically.And when I deleting or unpublishing a node, I want delete the shorter URL from UrlRewriting.config file automatically.
On the other hand, I  want **full control on saving, publishing and deleting process in Umbraco back office.**
PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the URL to the node, you can easily do so by modifying the [`umbracoUrlAlias`](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbraco-best-practices/umbracourlalias) property, instead of adding an entry to URLRewriting.config.

As far as adding logic when a node is saved, publish, deleted, etc., what you will do is create a class that subscribes to one or more of the many [Umbraco events](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events) and perform the logic there. See [Application startup events & event registration](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Events/application-startup) for more details.

Comment: I visited http://soetemansoftware.nl/ and I wanted download http://www.soetemansoftware.nl/downloads/umbracoeventoverview.pdf  .But it was damaged.

Comment: The content of the PDF is all available on that page. If you really need an offline version, just copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some examples for you:

```
public class SaveAndPublish : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        // Content Service
        ContentService.Created += ContentService_Created;
        ContentService.Saving += ContentService_Saving;
        ContentService.Published += ContentService_Published;
        ContentService.Trashing += ContentService_Trashing;

        // Media Service
        MediaService.Saving += MediaService_Saving;
        MediaService.Saved += MediaService_Saved;
        MediaService.Trashing += MediaService_Trashing;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ContentService_Created(IContentService sender, NewEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ContentService_Saving(IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ContentService_Published(Umbraco.Core.Publishing.IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {            
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ContentService_Trashing(IContentService sender, MoveEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void MediaService_Saving(IMediaService sender, SaveEventArgs<IMedia> e)
    {
        ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void MediaService_Saved(IMediaService sender, SaveEventArgs<IMedia> e)
    {
        foreach (var entity in e.SavedEntities)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void MediaService_Trashing(IMediaService sender, MoveEventArgs<IMedia> e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```